# Automated to do list in shortcuts app

Tags: notes.app, shortcuts-app

I have a note that has unchecked tick boxes (kinda like a to do list but in a note). I want to tick off one by one, let’s say for each second. The attached photo shows what kind of tick boxes i need to AUTOMATICALLY tick off. How to do this in shortcuts app?

[image]

Comment: You want to automatically tick off each task every second? How many tasks are there? Is each task really being 'completed' in one second, or do they mean something else?